# Canvas: drawImage progress

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, todataurl

I've written a large file upload plugin in JavaScript that allows a user to crop and resize images before they are uploaded using the canvas API. I was wondering if there was a was to check when running `drawImage` or `toDataURL` has completed. This would be useful when working with raw images of a couple MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript functions `drawImage` and `toDataURL` are synchronous functions.
That means that the functions will not execute the next function call until they are completely executed.

Having said that, you could use a simple `alert('done');` after the 2 function calls.

It is not possible to add a progressbar to these functions, however you could use a 'spinner' to indicate a slowly executing function

Comment: Thanks, thought as much